# c++: How to flip the binary values of each bit in int

Tags: c++, int, bit

Suppose I have an integer `int a`

In c++, as this `int` uses 4 bytes(32 bits) of memory, all bits would be occupied by either `1`'s or `0`'s. So, I wish to flip the values of each bit. That is, wherever in each bit there is `1` convert it to `0` and `0` to `1`.

Is there an easy way to go about this?

Edit: I also want to play with boolean algebra also. That is if I can execute basic boolean operations like addition, subtraction, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for the binary not operator (~).

So

```
int a = 0x04;
int b = ~a;
```

the value of `b` is 1111 1111 1111 1011 while the value of `a` is 0000 0000 0000 0100.

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) and the [GNU C](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Bitwise-Logical-Operators) have plenty of information of these *binary operators*.

Comment: This is exactly the thing which I was looking for. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of bitwise NOT operator:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int x = ~a;
    unsigned int y = ~a;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
-1
4294967295
```

For more information about binary operators and more try [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)